# Why this parametric function for an explicit cubic form?

Tags: parametric, interpolation, cubics

I'm trying to understand a statement [here](http://escience.anu.edu.au/lecture/cg/Spline/parametricCubicCurves.en.html). It states that the parametrisation of a cubic function is:
$$\begin{align}
x(t)&=a_xt^3+b_xt^2+c_xt+d_x\\
y(t)&=a_yt^3+b_yt^2+c_yt+d_y\\
\end{align}$$

Or in compact from
$$\begin{align}
P(x,y)&=at^3+bt^2+ct+d\\
\end{align}$$

being a, b, c and d 2d vectors.

But I can't get it. How do they get to this conclusion?

Comment: have you got i link or so?

Comment: Sorry don´t understand, what do you mean @Dr.SonnhardGraubner?

Comment: from which book is it?

Comment: I don't know if this came from a written book, I have provided the link I got it from in the description (click on the word "here").

Comment: which word do you mean?

Comment: This is the link I got it from: https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/curves/curves.html

Comment: the three components of a vector are each described by an polynomial of degree three which is usually called a cubic polynomial. what is the problem here?

Comment: @tired: I'm just asking why each parametric function is a cubic. Just that. It is not importnat here if we are talking about a 2d or 3d point.

Comment: how else would you model a degree three polynomial?

Comment: @tired: I have seen parametric functions comming for example from a explict cuadratic whose parametric functions are not cuadratic (just for example if t=x). Sorry if this is a dumb question. Perhaps I am overthinking it. But it is difficult for me to see how to describe the explicit function polinomial points we need to use 3 cubic parametric polinomials too for each axis. I was expecting some process or method applied to get to that functions :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that you are misinterpreting what the link say.  The text is:

> A parametric cubic curve in 3D is defined by: .....

so these equations are the definition of a parametric cubic curve (in $\mathbb{R}^3$), not the parametric representation of a cubic as:
$$y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \qquad (1)$$, that is a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

Added after the change in the question.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ the cubic $(1)$ can be expressed in the parametric form:
$$\begin{align}
x(t)&=a_xt^3+b_xt^2+c_xt+d_x\\
y(t)&=a_yt^3+b_yt^2+c_yt+d_y\\
\end{align}\qquad (2)$$

simply using $t=x$ and

$a_x=b_x=d_x=0 \quad,\quad c_x=1\quad,\quad a_y=a \quad,\quad b_y=b\quad,\quad c_y=c\quad,\quad d_y=d$

but note that, in general, a cubic expressed as $(2)$ with the coefficients of $t^2$ and $t^3$  not null, cannot be write in the form $(1)$.

Comment: I have changed my question to really reflect my own case use where I'm working on 2D and not 3D. Anyway it seems it stands the same... I was misundertanding the concept. And this two parametric functions hasn't been crafted working from the explicit form y=ax^3+b*x^2+c*x+d. Am I right? Anyway, if this is the explicit form of a cubic it could be possible to get to the parametric form in the link, couldn't it?

Comment: @Notbad: I've added something to my answer...I hope it's useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. Perhaps it is me not explaining correctly what I want to get but I would like to know how to get that paremetric functions x(t) and y(t). So, how a person can derive this two parametric funcions that define a cubic curve in R2. Perhaps the questions could be seen the other way around "Why this 2 parametric equations define a cubic curve in 2D". Again, I could be overthinking it. But I'm a bit obssesed to know where they came from. Thanks again for your time and efforts. If you prefer we could have a little chat to do it more quickly

Comment: After thinking more about it I have come to a conclusion. These guys just took this parametric functions for the curve because they just decided so. They were looking for a good balance between freedom and complexity and they decided that cubics were the one. After that they expressed 3 parametric cubic ecuations following explicit cubic form because they know they wanted a cubic as result and went further to see if they got to a good solution. Seems like a bit of let's see what happens. Could this be the case?

Comment: Now I understand your question!  And, yes, cubic spline are preferred because they are flexible but not too complex. You can see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation.